# Problem Caluclating Percentage Difference

Tags: finance, percentages

I am using the following to calculate the percentage difference.

```
priceDifference= newPrice - oldPrice;
priceDifferences= priceDifference/ oldPrice;
```

But When I use the caulation on two numbers 
Old Price £72.50 New Pirce £150.I only get a difference of 1.07% which is totally incorrect can anyone help me its to show in a program for example if a supplier has put their prices up or down by 20% to highlight it.

Sorry if I tagged the question wrong as new to the maths forum.

**Edit 1** 
Sorry I forgot renamed the functions for the post

**Edit 2** 
If I used this form with the values 72.50 and 150 it in-correctly shows its an increase of 10,689.66 when should be 106 %

```
percentage = (newPrice - oldPrice) / oldPrice * 100;
```

Comment: why are you not doing priceDifference / oldPrice in your formula? also you might want to multiply by 100 for a percentage

Comment: The first line calculates priceDifference, the second line uses priceDecrease which was never defined

Comment: @muzzlator I changed the names for the post amended it there now sorry. But it still gives me incorrect answer

Comment: The calculation shows that the old price inflated by $107 \% $ to £150.

Comment: Looks like you're multiplying by 100 twice somewhere, how are you printing the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forget to multiply by $100$ to converge your code to percentage. It should be

```
priceDifferences = priceDifference/ oldPrice * 100
```

or better still for clearer naming of variable:

```
percentageChange = priceDifference/ oldPrice * 100
```

We can indeed obtain the answer of $106.896551724 \%$.

To detect drastic changes, you can set a threshold and use an if statement to check

```
if abs(percentageChange) >= threshold:
     print("drastic change detected")
```

I am including a [Python code](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_5dM8ys2PvutuwQc.py) to illustrate that it works.

Comment: that was it but how do i deal with 20% higher and lower threshold I have got the higher working not the minus as the percentage is showing as postive and not negative

Comment: That is why I used the absolute value function.